# Twitter Streaming Tweets for all of the US

Tags: python, api, twitter, twitter-streaming-api

I am reading all of the data from http://econym.org.uk/gmap/states.xml which has all of the boundaries of the states. I want to get a stream of tweets from the USA only.  For some reason it never reaches my streamer class?

```
points = []
with open('states.xml') as fd:
    doc = xmltodict.parse(fd.read())

for pt in doc['states']['state']:
    lat = []
    lng = []
    for cord in pt['point']:
        lat.append(float(cord['@lat']))
        lng.append(float(cord['@lng']))
    points.extend([max(lat), max(lng), min(lat), min(lng)])

tweets = GetTweets(points)
#tweets = GetTweets([-122.75,36.8,-121.75,37.8,-74,40,-73,41])
```